# Яхонт, лал, рубин

Tags: этимология, славянизмы

Все это, насколько я знаю, названия одного и того же камня, который мы сейчас знаем как рубин. Но за его старорусское название выдают то "яхонт", то "лал". Я склонна считать, что все-таки второе - оно как-то больше похоже на русское слово, чем "яхонт". Хотя его происхождение тоже мне не понятно. Все ясно только с рубином - от латинского "rubrum" (кажется), красный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лал – древнерусское название рубина; неправильное название ювелирной прозрачной разновидности минерала шпинель красного, а точнее алого цвета: “ал лал”.  Возможно, тоже тюркизм, как и алый. 
 http://kristallov.net/shpinel.html

Есть скороговорка: Ал лал, бел алмаз, зелен изумруд,

Энциклопедия моды. Андреева Р., 1997 пишет: "древнерусское название некоторых драгоценных камней: просто яхонт - лал, рубин; яхонт красный -рубин; яхонт синий - сапфир; яхонт желтый - гиацинт; яхонт вишневый - аметист."

Яхонт - старославянское название красного ювелирного рубина [От греч. ‛υάκινθος — гиацинт], соответственно "яхонт лазоревый" - сапфир, с XIX в. термин употреблялся главным образом в художественной литературе.  http://www.moytagil.ru/e/2777291-yahont

Рубин - лат. rubens, rubinus — красный.

Было ещё одно устаревшее название - сардис.

Comment: http://jesuschrist.ru/lexicon/?word=%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81&dic=NikiforEncyc#.VOTmaOasUQ8

Answer (score 0):

> Но за его старорусское название выдают то "яхонт", то "лал".

В принуипе, и то и другое в каком -то смысле верно. В древнерусском тоже были синонимы.

Но тут - не совсем. "Яхонт" - попал в русский уже в средневековье, из польского.А дальние корни его, вроде бы в греческом,

> ЯХОНТ. Заим. в XVI в. из польск. яз., в котором jachant < ср.-в.-нем. jachant, восходящего через лат. посредство к греч. hyakinthos. Название драгоценного камня восходит к названию цветка гиацинта, в русском языке известного в латинизированной форме (с ц на месте к). Гиацинт назван по цвету крови (по преданию цветок вырос на крови убитого сына спартанского царя Эбара Гиакинфа). Форма яхуть у Афанасия Никитина — из тюркск. яз., куда это греч. слово попало из араб. яз.
>   Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь. — 2004 
>   (это Шанский, у него есть "оригиналные" прочтения, но тут я склонен верить)

Про Лал сказать нисего конкретного не могу, возможно из арабского (первое л напоминает артикль, но что модет значить не представляю).

Вообще надо проследить возможное изменение значений, в современном языке яхонт используется как архаизм, а вот "лал" почти исчез в значении "рубин".